# Randomly play clips from a selection of movies using VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have this working using the Python script from the following post:

[Playing random short clips from a collection of movies](https://superuser.com/questions/340834/playing-random-short-clips-from-a-collection-of-movies/1037750#1037750)

However, each clip opens VLC with a different window size (default for the video file I assume). How do I get it to open in full screen for every clip?

Answer (score 0):

In VLC --> Tools --> Preferences --> Video --> Check the Fullscreen box